# Ordered/Unordered list tag <ol><ul> does not display list bullets

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

Im new to programming/website building and recently downloaded an HTML5 template and have been customizing it via PHP. For some reason the list bullets do not appear on the rendered page when I enter the following coding:

```
<ol>
    <li>Data</li>
    <li>More data</li>
</ol>
```

(The ordered/unordered tags with the `li` for each new row)

Any idea on why this might be happening? Does something need to be added in the CSS? Or has the `<ol>` tag been updated to something different?

In case you want to take a look at the specific webpage, this is it: http://www.policehow.com/education2.php (The section under the "What You Can Do" part)

The bullets/ordered numbers aren't showing up

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing works"?

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by 'nothing works'? `ol` and `li` is just straightforward HTML.

Comment: looks just fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7KNXF/1/

Comment: The section looks good.. that is how li works.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine on your website. When you inspect the element, however, you'll see that `<ul>` elements have `padding:0;`. Once you remove that, it will work fine as you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4Eky/1/).

The padding comes from your very first line in the css.

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

You can add another rule for ul/ol

```
ul.showPadding, ol.show { padding: 40px; }
```

Now change your code to `<ul class="showPadding">` etc. Since you have many lists on many locations, I suggest using a specific class like this and not changing it for all elements.

Comment: Why would you add `!important` here? It's not needed & breaks the cascade.

Comment: I guess it can be left out, just thought it might be helpful

Comment: It means that if you want to change the padding on a different list (e.g. `<ul class="showPadding extraWide">`, you then need to use the `!important` flag on this too, to override the other important flag). Generally it's considered bad practice to use it unless really necessary, as you end up littering your CSS with overrides.

Comment: Yeah, it appears there was an unwanted "overflow:hidden;" tag in there causing problems. I'd like to add a little more padding than what's currently there, but the problem with doing that is it throws the grids out of whack and distorts the whole website. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding-left: 20px;` to the `ul` and it should work, they're just hidden from sight currently.